# Question about using BY or FROM

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> It might be breeding resentment to give irrelevant answers to the questions by your boss while you both are taking part in such an important convention, next week.

Answer (score 3):

No, To correct the sentence replace ***by*** with ***from***:

*It might be breeding resentment to give irrelevant answers to the questions **from** your boss while you both are taking part in such an important convention, next week.*

See the [Difference Between By and From](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-by-and-vs-from/):

> Grammatically speaking the words ‘by’ and ‘from’ are used as prepositions. The word ‘by’ indicates the instrumental case whereas the word ‘from’ indicates the ablative case.